# RecyclerView - jump to position, then smooth scroll to top

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with 50+ items. Each item contains an image (and text) and fills up most of the screen. I call `recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0)`, but the animation takes more than 3 seconds.

If I call `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(10)` and then `recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0)` the RecyclerView scrolls all the way from the bottom to the top (ignoring the request to "jump" to position 10).

Is there any way I can wait for the "jump" before calling `smoothScrollToPosition`?

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31235183/recyclerview-how-to-smooth-scroll-to-top-of-item-on-a-certain-position?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score -1):

mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);

recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);